# Scheme: About cond

Tags: lisp, scheme

`(cond ((test-1) (expression-1)))` 

When i use a cond, can i give the several functions in (expression-1)? 

Like this:

`(cond ((= 1 1) ((fun1) (fun2)) )`

Answer (score 7):

The `begin` is actually optional -- `cond` (in Scheme as well as in Emacs Lisp, at least) take multiple expressions after each test expression and evaluate them in turn in an implicit `begin`

```
(cond ((= 1 1) (fun1 ...) (fun2 ...))
      (t (something-else)))
```

Use `#t` instead of `t` for Scheme

Comment: There's an implicit `progn` (the `begin` equivalent) in each `cond` clause in Common Lisp as well. I think Clojure is different, since it doesn't have an additional paren pair wrapping each clause.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can execute multiple expressions by wrapping them in a `begin` as shown below

```
(cond ((= 1 1) (begin (fun1) (fun2)))
```

NOTE: The return value of the begin expression will the be result of last expression i.e in the example the return value will be of fun2 execution

Comment: For `cond` you don't even need to use `begin` in the result (you do, however, have to use it for `if`). This would be enough: `(cond ((= 1 1) (fun1) (fun2)))`